# nrpe (icinga) client service doesn't load/run

Tags: launchd, plist, monitoring

I just wrote following `.plist` file, which I put into `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, unluckily loading/running doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea what's wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/
PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/nrpe</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>/etc/nrpe.cfg</string>
      <string>-i</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Listeners</key>
      <dict>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>5666</string>
        <key>SockType</key>
        <string>stream</string>
        <key>SockFamily</key>
        <string>IPv4</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Wait</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.hasfailed.nrpe</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I used the installer referenced here: http://tbartelmess.github.io/NRPE-OSX/

Upon calling

```
launchctl load org.hasfailed.nrpe.plist
launchctl start org.hasfailed.nrpe
```

the following error shows up in my `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Sep 11 10:21:11 tc-mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (Listeners): assertion failed: 14F27: launchd + 30557 [C0446878-E8D0-3461-A226-91FF1C2B2DA6]: 0x30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed NRPE-OSX there is no need to create a second LaunchDaemon.

The installer creates - besides a user *nagios* and group *nagios* - a file named com.nagios.nrpe.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons with almost the same content as yours.

In addition you probably didn't change ownership of the file to root:staff and UserName/GroupName (admin/staff) in the plist are presumably false.